# passing string values with special characters to a function Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function that requires full name as an input, this name can have hyphens,apotrohpe,comma etc.

```
function AddOtherRefDoc(name, number) {
    var remove = "<a \href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='removeRefDoctor(this,'"+name+"',"+number+");'\">Remove</a>";
    var html = "<li><b> Referral Doctor: </b>"+name+"<b>, Referral No: </b>"+number+ " " +remove+" <input type='text' name='ref_docs' value='"+name+"'></input><input type='text'  name='ref_nos'  value='"+number+"'></input></li>";

    jQuery(opener.document).find("#r_docs").append(html);

}
```

The way I'm passing name to removeRefDoctor(), it's not working. How can I wrap this name into one string so that the function can accept this value.

Thanks a lot for ur help.

Answer (score 2):

It'd be easier for you to read and fix if you'd reimplement it like this for both variables:

```
var remove = $("<a/>")
    .attr('href', 'javascript:void(0);')
    .click(function() {
        removeRefDoctor(this,name,number);
     })
     .text('Remove');
```

Comment: Easier to read and would probably solve the problem as well.  Most likely there are problems with quotes in the name that mess up the generated html, closing the onclick attribute too soon.  Attaching the handler directly would solve that problem.

Comment: For name, The first and last names are separated by a comma. So If I pass in the name as it is, removeRefDoctor() will have 4 arguments instead of 3 so I need a way around that.

Answer (score 0):

I see some errors on the second line.

Use this

```
var remove = "<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" onclick=\"removeRefDoctor(this,"+name+","+number+");\">Remove</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using single quotes to quote the onclick attribute and to quote the `name` value passed in the function.  This closes your onclick attribute early.  You may also have single quotes in your `name` value.  You'll need to use double quotes around your name value and also escape any quotes to avoid html parsing issues.  Similarly, you'll need to escape quotes where you are using `name` as the value for your `<input />`

```
var attrName = name.replace(/'/g, '&#39;');
var jsName = attrName.replace(/"/g, '\\"');
```

Use it in your function like this:

```
function AddOtherRefDoc(name, number) {
    var attrName = name.replace(/'/g, '&#39;');
    var jsName = attrName.replace(/"/g, '\\"');

    var remove = "<a \href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='removeRefDoctor(this,\""+jsName +"\","+number+");'\">Remove</a>";
    var html = "<li><b> Referral Doctor: </b>"+name+"<b>, Referral No: </b>"+number+ " " +remove+" <input type='text' name='ref_docs' value='"+attrName+"'></input><input type='text'  name='ref_nos'  value='"+number+"'></input></li>";

    jQuery(opener.document).find("#r_docs").append(html);

}
```

That's the answer to why your code isn't working as you expect.  All that being said, I'd go with Mike Thompson's approach.  That makes a lot more sense and solves a lot of problems for you.